# How do I get window.history to work on Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, window, browser-history

I have a function in my javascript code that checks for certain parameters and if they are met, they should return the user to the previous page.  It all seems to work fine in chrome, but Firefox and IE do not respond to my function.

```
function doLoadLogin()
{
    _confirmNavigationChange = true
    var _indexPageArray = document.location.toString().split('/')
        _indexPageArray.pop()
    var _newURL = _indexPageArray.join('/');


    if(history.length <= 2)
    {
        //window.alert("miss")
        window.location = _newURL
    }
    else
    {

        //window.alert("hit")
        //history.back();  
        //history.go(-1);
        //window.history.back();  
        //window.history.go(-1); 
        //window.history.back(); return false;  
        //window.history.go(-1); return false;
        //location.href = document.referrer;
        //location.href = window.opener.location.href; 
    }
}
```

I have tried all of the lines (independently) in the else statement, but none of them work.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Membership functionality requires a server side language which can store session variables. On successful validation of the users credentials from the login page, your server side code will redirect the response to the login pages' referrer. When the user logs out you end their session by calling session_End and redirect them to the site landing page.

Comment: Hi Rob,  Thanks for looking at my question, unfortunately your response hasn't helped me.  Due to the specifics of our system, using windows.history is our only option so my question still stands.